# Why doesn't the reputation tab at the top notify me if I earn a privilege?

Tags: support, privileges, notifications

In StackOverflow,whenever I earn a privilege, I see that the reputation tab(achievement tab) turns green and when I press it,shows "You have earned xxx privilege" like this:

[image: Screenshot with the reputation tab opened]

Why doesn't such it notify me when I earn privileges here on Puzzling.SE? Also,how about making this a feature if this doesn't exist here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are considered a "veteran user" by the Stack Exchange software, which means you don't get notifications for certain privileges:

[image]

For more information, see [this post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151679/180276).

Comment: I see. What is a "veteran user"?

Comment: @CoolGuy, I wondered that too. Found the answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157523/274722 and here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138391/274722 "you're considered a veteran if you have received the association bonus, i.e. you have 200 rep somewhere."

Comment: @AE Thanks. So a *veteran* on SE is somebody who has experience on *a lot of different* sites, rather than *a lot of experience*. Good to know. (I guess I'm a veteran also.)